# firebase: create single database with multiple groups, each group with admin(s) and users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

App would be able to create a node in **`firebase`** db with a admin and users. How to create/differentiate admin/users within android app and not editing via **`firebase`** console.

I.e; A authenticated user(say admin) create a group on **`firebase-DB`** with a one Admin and adds emails-Id of other participants as users of the group.

similarly, each and every individual can create such isolated groups with a admin and users.

I have not idea how to do without editing `database` via **`FB-console`**.

Comment: You need a database structure?

Comment: @AlexMamo, yes. but can you please be more precise on how to get it without editing the Firebase-DB rules?

Comment: Firebase has only one kind of user so the concept of user types is not something Firebase does. To differentiate users, the user type would typically be stored within a users node you create;  /users/user_0/type: 'admin' and /users/user_1/type: 'user'. To prevent regular users from accessing admin data, set up Rules that allows users of type 'admin' to access that node. Likewise, when a user logs in, your app would read the users node to determine what kind of user it is and then allow additional features such as creating other users. Look at the Firebase getting started guides for help.

Comment: @Jay, thanks for your suggestion however, I don't want users to create other users. It is just a group with a admin and few users. admin notify/updates users with info and users just read.

Comment: @user755 You cannot prevent that. Anybody can create a user at any time without even being authenticated. They key is to control what users can access, and you do that via Firebase Rules. I wasn't suggesting allowing users to create other users and you can certainly set up an admin users/child users relationship but be aware users can be created at any time by anyone.